# How do I run a python script with a python.exe using C# (.NET6)?

Tags: python, c#, .net

## The Problem#

I have used other sites, other forums, and other Stackoverflow responses and I have crafted the code below, but Whenever I run the application and click the button connected to the run_cmd one of two things happens.

1. Nothing happens
2. A python window shows up for a millisecond and then goes away.

I have placed an input in the Python code to keep it running thinking that it was working but it was just completing and closing out, so I think it may be something else.

Any help would be great. ( sorry no Iron python)

python code filename: main.py

```
input("Is this working?")
```

C# Code
namespace HelloWorld

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void common_phrase_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void run_cmd()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe";
            start.Arguments = @"C\Users\user_name\PycharmProjects\Program_start\main.py";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.CreateNoWindow = false; 
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            start.RedirectStandardError = false; 
            Process.Start(start);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            run_cmd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the `WaitForExit` function, see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Also you may want to do some search around `ironpython`

Comment: Where and How should that be added? I tried adding the function and it was not letting me run it without an error.